# USB mouse shuts down the laptop!

Tags: windows-7, usb

For the past two days, whenever I plug in my USB mouse (which has been working for a long time, previously) into the laptop, my computer restarts! I tried changing mice, but the same thing happens.

I have 3 ports, usually, I try one port and the laser does not come on, then I try another one and the laser comes and and off, then I again take out and put it in any port and the damn thing just turns off the computer.

Specs: Windows 7 Ultimate 64-bit, 4GB RAM, Fujitsu 532ah i5 laptop

Comment: @Amr ElGarhy yes, superuser might be more appropriate for these kind of questions, but stackoverflow is a technology q&a site also, and this question seems relevant (to me)

Comment: From the about page: "Stack Overflow is a programming Q & A site that’s free.". It's not a technology site, it's a programming site.

Comment: @Ryan: If your system reboots upon inserting a USB mouse, then the system may have crashed.  Try holding down F8 before Windows starts, select "Disable restart on system failure", and insert the mouse after you have logged in.  If a Stop error (blue screen) occurs, please post the error codes, like STOP: 0xXXXXXXXX (...) and the name of the error, which is in all caps, if displayed (such as IRQL_NOT_LESS_THAN_OR_EQUAL).

Comment: Hey! Thanks for writing. I went ahead and bought a wireless mouse (was also a bit scared if the comp filesystem would get corrupted with the constant "mouse forced shutdowns") , its working without a problem. Thank you (everyone) who took the time to try to help me, I really appreciate it! I am sure with your help I would have solved the issue in time had I not picked up the new mouse.   Thanks again!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This sounds like it's a driver problem. Did you update anything lately? If you did, you may want to roll back your driver. If you hadn't updated anything before this started, then I would suggest maybe reinstalling the drivers, or getting a new one.

Comment: It's been a crazy past few days, lots of updates, can you give me a hint as to which drivers to change? Thanks!

Comment: Doesn't seem like a driver to me - I don't think HID drivers get updated much (at all?). Does plugging anything else into that port cause problems, or is it just the mouse?

Comment: A driver would not turn on/off the mouse laser... that's powered by the USP port and always on.

Comment: @Ryan if your mouse came with any installation cds then the drivers would be on there, otherwise check the manufacturer's site, they probably would have something there

Answer (score 3):

it can be a damaged usb port or usb controller itself. if the internal circuit of your usb port is damaged then their may be a short circuit when you plug your mouse. you can try a different usb component like pen drive to check if the problem is with your usb port or mouse itself.

Comment: Ok, USB flash drives and a wireless mouse seems to be working...

Answer (score 1):

Windows 7 does have a built in troubleshooter (http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Troubleshooting-in-Windows) though I think KayKay is onto something inasmuch as your USB ports may have shorted out.

Comment: Nope, the USB ports are working with a wireless mouse, charging my phone, and usb memory (flash and hdd)

Answer (score 0):

We have a mouse here (oldschool ballmouse, USB) that shuts down my PC when i connect it, furthermore it just wont appear connected at all when we try and connect it to a laptop

Conclusion: Mouse causes USB shortage, motherboard dislikes